# How to parse multiple cells in one go using ImportJSON()?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-custom-function, json

I have a dataset with 14 columns. Two of the columns contain text that is in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

I am currently parsing the data with [ImportJSON()](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON), a script that is a collection of [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). It has been available for Google Sheets since 2012 and is widely used.

I have found a way to parse the contents in the JSON cells one by one, but it is slow to do that over all the rows, and the formulas become prone to showing `Loading...` ([issue 222342097](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097).)

How do I efficiently parse the JSON data in a column row by row using one array formula instead of parsing every cell separately?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE.  ImportJson is not a [Google Sheets Function](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).  Please take the [Tour] and review [ask], then [edit] your question to include enough detail that the problem is understood. 
 Include a sample of your data before and an example of the expected result.  Also, include any formulas you are using as well as any error messages you are encountering.